# Should similar screens be different Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, architecture, code-duplication, clean-architecture

Ok so I'm creating an app. I have a "Creation" page, and a "Detail" page for the same item. The UI is the same, probably the logic will be the same as well, only difference i can think of now is that when creating, the Object backing my UI is local, and as an argument in the fragment I get the item "Name", when showing the detail, the argument is the item's "ID" and the data backing my UI is remote.

My question is, following clean architecture and all around good programming rules, is it better to separate this screen in 2 almost identical Fragments, separating concerns and allowing for future differentiations, also possibly avoiding a "god fragment" but having a lot of possible code duplication, or is it better to keep them in the same screen, avoiding code duplication?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, you should avoid code duplication as much as you can. I don't know how deep and complex is your app, but if you have two almost identical fragments, I would use a 'ParentFragment' that contains the common code, and extend your Fragments from it. This way you can customize both fragments in the future, while maintaining the common features.

Comment: Hi Carlos, thanks for your opinion. Yes code duplication is usually to be avoided, but based on the principle of "Composition over inheritance" using a 'Parent fragment' is not the best way to do it.